# Tags of X equivalent of Y kind of question

Tags: discussion, tags

There are many questions are of *X equivalent of Y* form:

> What's the Java equivalent of XXX in C++?
>
> What's the Linux equivalent of XXX in Windows?
>
> Is there a XXX in Ruby like Python's?

Some of the questions are tagged with both X and Y. For example:

[What is the equivalent of Java's final in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327544/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javas-final-in-c)

[What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)

It makes sense in a way, as whoever has knowledge of both the fields has a better chance of providing the answer, but I think it's better tagged with only the X tag.

Is there a general rule on this topic?

Comment: Personally I think they are OK provided the usual research effort is shown. These are not the same as "convert my code from X to Y" questions.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I think you misread - the question is about tagging.

Comment: @Dukeling: Oops.

Answer (score 2):

> I think it's better tagged with only the X tag.

I completely agree. If you're looking for a question about Y, this question won't help you at all, as it is actually about X.

However, those questions, as they stand, can't work with only one of the tags.

> What is the equivalent of Java's `final` in C#?

If you are a C# expert, you may still have no knowledge of Java's `final` keyword, and thus won't understand the question.

The concept needs to be explained well enough such that anyone with zero knowledge of the source language (Java) completely understands it.

Comment: Your last sentence is kinda complicated but I think that "is" doesn't belong there :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I believe it was correct (consider it with some brackets added - "... knowledge of (the language (the concept we're looking for an equivalent of) is in) ..."), but I simplified it a bit.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. Somehow I thought the second sentence didn't need / already had a verb.